# Before taking Samadhi Dnyaneshwar did follow Ashtangyoga?

Tags: history, yoga, saint, samadhi

Ashtangyoga contains 8 parts in yoga. Ashta means 8.

Ashtangyoga - Yam Niyam Aasan Pranayam Pratyahar Dharana Dhyan Samadhi

These are eight parts of Ashtangyoga. The saint Dnyaneshwar has taken Samadhi. It is very difficult to go upto last stage of Ashtangyoga. Common man can not go upto that stage. Did Dnyaneshwar followed all these steps?

Comment: No. He did not practiced Ashtangyoga yoga .Nivruttinatha has  given him the Diksha of  Nath-tradition. But as it is believed he was avatara of Lord Vishnu (Narayana) and was born yogi. AFAIK  Nivruttinatha by method of Shaktipata transferred  all the yogic knowledge  to him.